# QGIS Clipping and reprojecting SRTM data creates a HUGE file

Tags: qgis-2

I'm having difficulty in QGIS doing what should be a very simple thing and I haven't been able to find anyone who has had the same issue.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**  I need to export a very specific clipped region of elevation data from SRTM tiles in .bin format.  It needs to be in my local UTM zone projection.

**Problem:**  This should be simple but the process I'm using creates a runaway file size that fills my hard disk.

**My process is:**

1. Download SRTM tiles (SRTM3 data version 2.1 from http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/North_America/
2. Import as layers of raster data.  CRS is WGS84
3. Change project CRS to UTM zone 18 (EPSG:32618) enabling "reproject on the fly".  (Note - some of the data in in zone 17, but not the area I am trying to clip)
4. Raster->Misc->Merge.  This works properly and creates a 23.1MB file which loads into the canvas as a layer.  Remove all other layers to clean things up.
5. Raster->Extract->Clipper.  Mode "Extent"  Enter extent coordinates manually.  The area is very small - perhaps 10 miles by 10 miles.  The dialog appears to freeze but if you look at the output file it is building, it expands to gigabytes in size eventually filling the hard disk after an hour or two and generating an error.  The file size is around 300 gigabytes when it errors.

I suspect the problem is related to my merge/reprojection and subsequent extraction of the merged rasters.  If I simply clip a small section from a single tile without reprojection or merge, it works instantly, creating a small file.  However, my scenery crosses tiles and I cannot extract the area I wish without first merging the SRTM tiles together, as far as I can tell.

I'm brand new to QGIS and GIS in general and am trying to use SRTM data as elevation data for a Condor soaring flight simulation scenery landscape.  If anyone has a better suggestion or tool for exporting clipped SRTM data to the .bin format, I'd welcome it.

Comment: Do a real reprojection instead of on the fly. That should work.

Comment: Hmm, that works!  At least, it fixes the file size issue.  Unfortunately, it switches to decimal degrees when I do the reproject.  I have carefully calculated all of my clipping extents based on pixels - the scenery program is extremely picky about this.  How can I use pixels to designate the clipping extent, or where can I find out how to convert them to decimal degrees?

Answer (score 2):

Clipping is done in QGIS in the background using GDAL. This just looks at the files on your disk, and does not know anything you have set as project CRS or on-the-fly-reprojection.

So if you need your data in UTM 17N, firstly, reproject the SRTM using `Save As ...` into that CRS, add that to your project, and remove the degree layer.

Turning `On-the-fly-reprojection` **OFF** is very helpful to avoid such mistakes.

It does not matter if some part of your area falls into the next UTM zone, reprojection will do anyway.